# Android: How to use okhttp3 to send a PUT request with payload parameters

Tags: android, okhttp

I have tried many different ways to send a PUT request with a payload by using okhttp3, but none of them can work, could any one show me how to use okhttp3 to do this work, please? I just paste some key header information from Chrome Browser.

```
    General:
    Request URL:http://8.102.239.245/abc/api/108/actions?name=Rename
    Request Method:PUT

    Request Headers: 
    Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

    Query String Parameters: 
    name:Rename

    Request Payload: 
    {id: 108, name: "dbd"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to add Retrofit as well in order to facilitate API definition:

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'`

Once added, do the following:

1. Define an interface and your request as a method:

   ```
   public interface MyService {
       @PUT("abc/api/{id}/actions")
       Call<YourResponse> putName(@Path("id") int id, @Query("name") String name);
   }
   ```
2. Instantiate your API using your OkHttpClient:

   ```
    MyService myService = okHttpClient.create(MyService.class)
   ```
3. Issue your request:

   ```
   Call<YourResponse> call = myService.putName(108, "Rename");
   call.enqueue(new Callback<YourResponse>() { ... };
   ```

Comment: Hi Chisko, thank you for replying. but where should I put the payload parameter, such as {id: 108, name: "dbd"}

Comment: You put it when you call (step 3) the service method (step 1), see how the specific path is substituted thanks to the `@Path` annotation, and the `@Query` annotation allows defining the query parameter name in a convenient way

Comment: But you have put "Rename" as @Query parameter, where should I put the "dbd" parameter? if I replace it with "dbd", then where should I put the "Rename"? because as chrome browser's info, name=Rename and {id:108, name:"dbd"} are in different sections, "Rename" is belong to Query String Parameters, and "dbd" is belong to Request Payload

Comment: Put the specific parameters you need when issuing the request (step 3). Replace "rename" for "dbd"

Comment: Hi Chisko, thanks for your help. I figured out the way. I created a "RenameBean" which can holds the id and new name, and put a @Body with RenameBean instance after your @Query("name")